# excel vba unloading contents from a form

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that is opened when a user clicks a button in a worksheet. After clicking the button, if the user inputs some data, then decides to close the form, the previously entered data remains in the form. How can (in code) I get rid of that data so it opens with the default every time the button is clicked?

Currently I just use

```
form.Show
```

when the button is clicked and

```
form.Hide
```

when the user hits the cancel button within the form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `form.Hide` to `Unload Me`

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the closing event and call unload inside like this

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer) 
   Unload Me  
End Sub
```

Comment: Chuck you don't need to call `Unload Me` from UserForm_QueryClose(). The user already has a Cancel Button from where he can call the code